# Python variable scope,why does funcs prints same value?

Tags: python

I have this program:

```
funcs = { idx: lambda: print(idx) for idx in range(5) }
```

In essence, we have a dictionary of indices and functions:

```
{0: <function __main__.<dictcomp>.<lambda>()>,
 1: <function __main__.<dictcomp>.<lambda>()>,
 2: <function __main__.<dictcomp>.<lambda>()>,
 3: <function __main__.<dictcomp>.<lambda>()>,
 4: <function __main__.<dictcomp>.<lambda>()>}
```

However, the following function calls have the same result:

```
funcs[4]()
4
funcs[0]()
4
```

Why do I get `4` as output both times, even though I am using different inputs?

Comment: You have 5 functions that all say "print the current value of `idx`". The current value of `idx` after the loop is 4.

Comment: So it's a story about the local variable `idx`. When you call the functions (whichever) it is going to print the variable `idx` which is not the key, but the last value taken by the range. Now I don't know the correct syntax to print the key.

Comment: @khelwood I'm not sure that's the best dupe but I'm struggling to find a canonical.

Comment: You basically want: `{idx: lambda idx=idx: print(idx) for idx in range(5)}` because `idx` the print refers to in your code is the last bound value... (4 in this case)... the `idx=idx` binds the variable present at the time instead... Not sure what the best dupe is for this...

Comment: Jon,now dict is ordered?

Comment: @MikiBelavista what difference does that make?

Comment: I thought indexing problem would be solved.

Comment: @MikiBelavista it's not anything to do with indexing, it's to do with late binding and parameter names. The lambdas all refer to the same value

Comment: Ok,I understand now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>You are accessing the same object each time, since `dict` are not ordered, and accessing them by index does not do what you expect</s>

```
funcs = {
        idx: lambda: print(idx, end=' ') for idx in range(5)
        }

for f in funcs:
    print(f, id(f))

print('#'*20)

for idx in range(5):
    print(id(funcs[idx]()))

0 1477866096
1 1477866128
2 1477866160
3 1477866192
4 1477866224
####################
4 1477430720
4 1477430720
4 1477430720
4 1477430720
4 1477430720
```

The previous explanation is wrong. What actually happens is this:

The lambdas were constructed using `idx in range(5)`. When a lambda is called, no matter the caller idx parameter (*i.e. it doesn't matter what `idx`is inside`funcs[idx]()`*) the lambda is using the `idx` from `range(5)`. Since the `range(5)` now (at its end) points to 4, that is the `idx` each lambda uses, resulting in all of them printing 4.

The lambda are different objects, but they still all use the current inner `idx`.

Here is an example that helped me:

```
ls=[]
for i in range(2):
    ls.append(lambda : print(i))

for f in ls:
    print(id(f), end=' ')
    f()

for i in range(3,5):
    ls.append(lambda : print(i))


for f in ls:
    print(id(f), end=' ')
    f()

44467888608 1 # 1st lambda - uses the last idx (for range was 2)
44467888336 1 # 2nd lambda - uses the last idx (for range was 2)
44467888608 4 # 1st lambda - uses the current last idx (2nd for range was 5)
44467888336 4 # 2nd lambda - uses the current last idx (2nd for range was 5)
44467921240 4 # 3rd + 4th lambdas
44467921512 4
```

Comment: I found this example on net. Can we change idx: lambda: construct to get the ordered dicts?

Comment: Not sure I understand your suggestion. How would exactly the lambda would look like?

Comment: In your second `for` loop, you're just printing the id of `None` 5 times. That's not really illustrating anything useful. It's not the indexes that's the problem.

Comment: Yeah, I'm in the middle of fixing/deleting this... It's not right as it is currently